# ReactJS. Infinity loop

Tags: reactjs

I'am getting props from child in `getCount` function. And set it prop into state. Than i try set it in component and get infinity loop. How can i fix that?

There is code of parent component:

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
import Message from "./Message/Message";

export default class Widget extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: {
        s: 30,
        l: 60,
        a: 1
      },
      counter: 0
    };
  }

  getCount = count => this.setState(state => ({
    counter: count
  }));

  getColor = color => {
    console.log(`the color is ${color}`);
  };

  render() {
    const counter = this.state.counter;

    return (
      <div>
        <Message
          getColor={this.getColor}
          getCount={this.getCount}
          color={this.state.color}
        >
          {undefined || `Hello World!`}
        </Message>
        {counter}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**child:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Message extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);

    this.state = { h: 0 };
    this.counter = 0;
  }

  changeColor = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      h: Math.random()
    }));
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    this.props.getColor(this.color);
    this.props.getCount(this.counter);
  }

  render() {
    this.counter++;
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { s, l, a } = this.props.color;

    this.color = `hsla(${this.state.h}, ${s}%, ${l}%, ${a})`;

    return (
      <p
        className="Message"
        onClick={this.changeColor}
        style={{ color: this.color }}
      >
        {children}
      </p>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is second component (Message) ?

Comment: Why did you name your function an `getCount` but you actually set the count?

Comment: I think you need to make it as a function `{() => this.getColor()}`

Comment: wait i post. second component is ok. i try to show it in console.log() in getState and i got count

Comment: The problem is likely in your `Message` component.

Comment: The Reason, because i want to set to state count and than display it in this component

Comment: Tico, i added arrow function, but i still get infinity loop `Maximum update depth exceeded.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your `Message` component.

You are using `getCount()` inside your `componentDidUpdate()` method. This causes your parent to re-render, and in turn your `Message` component to re-render. Each re-render triggers another re-render and the loop never stops.

You probably want to add a check to only run the function if the props have **changed**. Something like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(prevProps.color !== this.props.color) {
    this.props.getColor(this.color);
    this.props.getCount(this.counter);
  }
}
```

This will keep the functionality you need, but prevent, not only the infinity-loop, but also unnecessary updates.

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay, hmm it "could". Hard to say in this scenario because I don't have the full picture of this app. With `sCU` you would prevent a re-render completely. This app might require a re-render but without updating the parent.

Comment: Yeah it might halt the render for different use cases. `componentDidUpdate` it is then

Comment: @Chris, now component is not rerender

Comment: @Chris I mean now in state.counter = 0 all time

Comment: @МаратАлембиков even when you change color?

Comment: @Chris, yes. I click on message and. Now getColor and getCount not work

Comment: @МаратАлембиков oh I see now. Your `this.state.color` changes but not `this.color` because you calculate it inside `render()`. However render won't trigger unless parent color is changed. You can add to my solution: `if(prevProps.color !== this.props.color || prevState.color !== this.state.color) {`. Also add the `prevState` parameter to the function.